# Visual Studio 2008 XML editor disappeared?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

My visual studio xml editor is gone. So when I open for example a web.config file it's shown like a plain text file. If I right click -> Open with: the XML Editor option it's not longer there. Anyone had this problem before??. I've tried repairing the installation and uninstall/install but it didn't fixed it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only issue that I can see surviving a install/reinstall is a supressed package load failure.  Try running the following from a command shell.  I'm assuming that Visual Studio is installed at the location "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0"

```
"c:\program files\microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\common7\ide\devenv.cmd" /ResetSkipPkgs
```

This will reset all skipped package suppression.

If this works then at some point in time when starting VS or loading a file you were presented with a crytpic dialog that said "Some XML Package failed to load ... " and had a yes/no option.  Choosing yes will prevent VS from loading that package in the future and hence preventing the XML editor from loading.

I believe this value is stored within a user registry hive.  So it's possible that it would survive uninstall.  If this works please let me know as I'd like to file a bug.

**Edit** I was able to confirm with the owner of this /ResetSkipPkgs feature that this issue will be fixed in the next version of Visual Studio (post VS2008).

Comment: It did work, thanks a lot! I dont remember VS showing any dialog about a package load fail or anything like that. It's devenv.exe by the way.

Comment: @Pablote, glad I could help.  I've been bitten by this several times at work.  It's weird that it would survive re-install.  I'm going to ping someone about this later today.

Comment: I faced the same problem right now in vs2008; The command solved the problem, but I could not find devenv.cmd; I tried devenv.exe and it works