# Visual Studio 2008 Xaml Editor not working / disappeared

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, xaml

When I start up VS 2008 to work on a WPF / Silverlight App and open a XAML or XML file the XAML / XML editor is no longer working.  The designer does not show up and intellisense is unavailable.  It basically looks like a text file has been opened.

Comment: This has happened to me once, but sorry can't remember how to fix it. Just attesting this question that it happens. Will answer if I remember

Comment: There is another question up there I found when googling for the answer, but it only references the XML editor.  I just wanted to get a question up there that mentioned the XAML editor (they are the same thing, basically) so people googling for the problem would get another SO answer

Comment: See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/dd6f14ed-e582-4b49-9358-64f2afaec151 , I think this should have the subtitle, I installed windows 2008 SDK and now my XAML intellisense is gone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try running the following command.

> "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\ide\devenv" /resetSkipPkgs

If that doesn't work try repairing the Visual Studio Install

- Start -> Control Panel
- Add Remove Programs
- Select VS
- Choose repair

Comment: This is overkill. The solution is just to re-register the TextMgrP.dll.

Comment: @Jeff, not necessarily. There are numerous problems that can cause this behavior in VS.  This solution is the one most likely to fix the problem.  Re-registering that DLL will only fix one very specific problem.  I've found the package reload issue to be much more common than a non-registered DLL.

Comment: This is essentially what the other post says, either the /resetSkipPkgs switch or the /setup switch.  Just trying to get an answer for people looking for the XAML editor based answer.

Comment: @Jared: The designer rarely works, regardless of the package loading and the broken intellisense is a known issue fixed by re-registering the TextMgrP.dll. Trying this first and then attempting your other suggested options would be prudent as it is quick, and if it works, it saves a lot of time.

Comment: @Jeff, I disagree with your "rarely works" statement. I have VS installed on many many machines and rarely see a problem with it working.  Re-registering textmgrP.dll has *never* fixed a problem I've had.  That's not saying it won't work but every problem I've seen has come down to a bad install or a suppressed one time package load failure.

Comment: Installing VS 2008 SP1 will help..it fixed similar problems which i had encountered.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=27673C47-B3B5-4C67-BD99-84E525B5CE61&displaylang=en

Answer (score 4):

The designer for XAML is awful. Do yourself a favour and set your XAML files to open in the code viewer instead; they'll load quicker and you won't have to deal with the designer's flakiness.

However, to fix the intellisense, just re-register TextMgrP.dll using regsvr32 as [indicated here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953196).

Comment: I whole-heartedly agree. I just used the designer in my answer, based on the wording in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem before, running [this command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276.aspx) should fix it :

```
Devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the file, select "Open With", and then choose "Windows Presentation Foundation Designer", does that work? If so, most likely the default editor for .xaml files has changed. You can reset this back to the designer by pressing "Set as Default" when the designer you want is selected in the list in the Open With dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an XML package that was previously not loaded, see other question here;
[Visual Studio 2008 XML Editor Disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541548/visual-studio-2008-xml-editor-disappeared)

Also, there is an [answer on the Silverlight forums](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/45298.aspx) that describes using the "devenv /setup" command that can be found in (VS2008InstallationDirectory)\IDE.

Answer (score 0):

AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!!!!  It finally worked!!!!!  Only after a week of pulling my hair out.  I had multiple issues.

1. Xaml editor and add DataSource Wizard and other things would not work with VS 2008.
2. Tried to install SP1.  It would not let me because Office Suite 2007 was in the middle of an SP1 update and would not finish.
3. Un-installed Microsoft office and reinstalled and service packed.
4. Tried devenv /setp & devenv /resetskippkgs to no avail.
5. Finally service packed VS2008.
6. Retried the devenv /setp & devenv /resetskippkgs twice and voila!!  It worked.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problems when i installed VS2008 Professional over an existing VS2008 Express edition. Suddenly my XAML designer stopped working . i got failed loading the XAML dll error.
So  i just uninstalled all VS Express stuff  and then installed VS 2008 SP1 fixed all things.

try link below for VS 2008 SP1.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=27673C47-B3B5-4C67-BD99-84E525B5CE61&displaylang=en