# xaml editor not available in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

I was using VISUAL STUDIO 2012,2010 and 2005.
Later I uninstalled 2012 and 2005 and installed 2008.
Now I can not open xaml files in 2010.
When I give OpenWith option for xaml files it shows only a few options as below. [image]

Do any one have any solution?

Comment: What happens when you try each one?

Comment: I have only 2008 and 2010. In 2008 it is possible to open xaml

Comment: Hello any one to answer??

Comment: Try following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859335/visual-studio-2008-xaml-editor-not-working-disappeared?lq=1 (that's for 2008 so will need minor adaptation for 2010). Failing that, try re-installing VS2010.